# FullScreen not working when move to other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullscreen

The follow example working perfect when we are in the same page `index.html` If I click some other page `about.html` the fullscreen will automatically drops down.

I want to achieve fullscreen mode continuously visible until we manually change. 
Anyone help me to achieve this.

```js
var elem = document.documentElement;
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="openFullscreen();" href="#">Open FullScreen</a>

<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have voted to close, based on duplicate as `@Cue` stated. I will add though... you could use a `manifest.json` technique to add your site as fullscreen on a device with Android Chrome on it, making your entire site look fullcreen on Android as long as you make your site as a single page, which can easily look like multiple pages. Once again as you navigate away it will leave fullscreen mode, though.

Comment: @StackSlave great. I understand. I prefer your answer is final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected (and [well documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode)) behaviour.

> Navigating to another page, changing tabs, or switching to another application using any application switcher (or Alt-Tab) will likewise exit full-screen mode.

You'll have to have the user activate fullscreen mode on each new page they visit.

Comment: But when I click `F11` in keyboard its works. possible to trigger using js?

Comment: That enables the browser into fullscreen mode, which is different than using the fullscreen API. Using the fullscreen API, you are able to specify an element in fullscreen mode.